# How do I get rid of b' if I want to parse a bash output using python?

Tags: python, line-breaks

At my python application I'm doing the following to get some values from a larger JSON

```
ffgrading_json = exec_command(f'{options["path_ffprobe"]} -loglevel quiet -print_format json -read_intervals "%+#2" -select_streams v:0 -show_entries side_data "{path}" | egrep -m 1 -A 10 "Mastering display metadata" | grep -v "Mastering display metadata"|tr -d "[:space:]"| tr -d "\n"')
```

on the bash console, the raw command returns the following:

`"red_x":"34000/50000","red_y":"16000/50000","green_x":"13250/50000","green_y":"34500/50000","blue_x":"7500/50000","blue_y":"3000/50000","white_point_x":"15635/50000","white_point_y":"16450/50000","min_luminance":"50/10000","max_luminance":"40000000/10000"`

But if I write the output to a file using python like so:

```
with open('/tmp/grading.json', 'w') as f:
                f.write(str(ffgrading_json))
```

The following will get written:
 `b'"red_x":"34000/50000","red_y":"16000/50000","green_x":"13250/50000","green_y":"34500/50000","blue_x":"7500/50000","blue_y":"3000/50000","white_point_x":"15635/50000","white_point_y":"16450/50000","min_luminance":"50/10000","max_luminance":"40000000/10000"'`

Not sure how important it is but this is my exec_command function:

```
def exec_command(string):
    """
    Shell command interface
    Returns returnCode, stdout, stderr
    """
    log('DEBUG', f'[Command] {string}')
    output = run(string, shell=True, check=True, capture_output=True)
    return output.returncode, output.stdout, output.stderr
```

The question now is, how can I get rid of `b'` and where does it come from ???

Comment: Because you are writing *bytes* object to a file opened in *text* mode. Maybe just open the file in binary mode, or convert the bytes to `str` before writing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `.decode()` on the `output.stdout` the output is in bytes so this will convert it to a string

when you print `bytes` python tries to convert what it can into `ascii characters` but it will display `b''` around the printed data to indicate that the variable you printed contains `bytes` and it is not a `string`

Comment: Much better, now it's working. Thanks for that hint. I will mark your answer asap.